# python rand function conditional operator combination

Tags: python, numpy

what does this line of code actually do?
Case 1: if number returned by the rand function is **less than 0.8** what it does?
Case 2: if number returned by the rand function is **greater than 0.8** what it does?
Here is the line of code -
**msk = np.random.rand(len(df)) < 0.8**

Comment: It assigns either `True` or `False` to the variable `msk`.

Comment: It return true false accoding to your random number

Answer (score 0):

```
Case 1: if number returned by the rand function is less than 0.8 what it does? 
 > The code will return 'True' because the value is less than 0.8 

Case 2: if number returned by the rand function is greater than 0.8 what it does?
> Again the result will be 'False' as the value here is outside the scope of the variable declared.
```